# How to solve: several ifs with more or less the same code?

Tags: design-patterns, if-statement, method-call

I have this code:

```
if(condition 1) {
    if(condition X) {
        myMethod(..., paramx, ...);
    }

    if(condition Y) {
        myMethod(..., paramy, ...);
    } 
 }

if(condition 2) {
    if(condition A) {
        myMethod(..., parama, ...);
    }

    if(condition B) {
        myMethod(..., paramb, ...);
    } 
 }
...
```

And so on. As you see, I am calling the same method with just one different parameter according to the conditions. Whats an elegant way to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(condition 1){
   if(condition X){  
      dependentVar = paramx;  
   }

   if(condition Y){
      dependentVar = paramy;
   } 
}

if(condition 2){
   if(condition A){
      dependentVar = parama;
   }

   if(condition B){
      dependentVar = paramb;
   } 
}
```

...
At last :

```
myMethod(..., dependentVar, ...);
```

*If nothing ,this will improve the readability  of the code.*

**Obviously ,this is assuming that exactly (and at most) one of the conditions is satisfied**

Comment: I think they are not equal solution:)  In the question, there will be 0-4 method calls depends on the conditions.  But in this one, there will be 1 method call in any conditions.

Comment: Under the constraints you are specifying ,yes, they are not equivalent.This is a cleaner solution under an assumption that i have just stated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[**Strategy pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is what you need to use.  Decisions will be made in strategy objects, and you will just call them all one by one until one of them replies positively.